# Finding the dimension of the Kernel $\mathbb{R}^{3*2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_4[x]$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, image-processing, dimension-theory-algebra

**Approximate Question asked in Exam**
You have an $\mathbb{R}^{3*2}$ matrix with linear transformation to $\mathbb{R}_4[x]$ (polynomial of degree $5$). Now you had to find the dimension of the Kernel.

I Choose an answer that said the The Dimension of the Kernel is $< 3$.
Is this correct?

Comment: $\text{dim}(\mathbb{R}^6)=\text{dim(Ker)}+\text{dim(Image)}$ where the dimension of the image is $\le 5$.

Comment: @Daniil Thanks m8